# Proof integral equality in complex

Tags: integration

I need to proof that:
$$\int_{\gamma}\frac{e^{iz}}{z^2+a^2}dz=\frac{e^{-a}}{2ia}\int_{\gamma}\frac{dz}{z-ia}$$
Can anyone help me please?
($a \gt 0$ is a real number)

Comment: Cauchy integral?

Comment: $\gamma$ is supposed to be a closed curve? Moreover: when you *prove* something, you produce a *proof*. *proof* is a noun, not a verb

Comment: Yes, sorry, γ is closed curve.

Comment: For a general closed curve, this is not correct IMHO. Just take a circle centered ar $-ia$ of radius $|a|/2$, then the RHS is zero whereas the LHS is not

Comment: ok. but how can i get from the left side of the equation to the right side?

after i get it i will have to using half circle closed curve, the first one is from -R to R and the second is half of circle. then i have to take R to infi. is it right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use two step in the computation,

1. First observe that $\frac {1}{z^2+a^2} = \frac{1/2}{z-ia} - \frac{1/2}{z+ia}$
2. Then use the properties of meromorphic functions. The integral on a loop $\gamma$ will give you the residue times $2 \pi i$ of all poles inside the given loop as a result. Check the "residue formula" for exemple in Stein Shakarchi.

Comment: I unable to get from left side of the equlation to the right one. :(

Comment: now i have: $$ \frac{e^{iz}}{2ia} \cdot \oint _{\gamma }\left [\frac{1}{z-ia} - \frac{1}{z+ia} \right ]$$

Comment: So now. because i don't have any pole for z=-ia inside my curve $$\frac{1}{z+ia}$$ is equal to 0 ?

Comment: Wait, you cannot put $e^{iz}$ out of the integral, $z$ is not even defined outside of it. You need to understand now what is the residue of $\frac {e^iz}{z-ia}$.